# Receiving data from JavaScript into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

> Working example below, hopefully this will help others learn!

I'm using AJAX in javascript to send a JSON string to PHP.

I'm not familiar with AJAX, javascript or php, so this is taking me a while to get started.

I have a html file with a username field, password field, and login button.

Then I have a javascript file that takes the username pass and sends it to a php file.

I know the php file is being accessed because I am seeing the test echo in console.

I just cant figure out how to access the data I'm sending to the php.

script.

```
function attemptLogin(){

var inputUserName = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("userName").value);


var ajaxData = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxData.open('GET', 'ajax.php', true);
ajaxData.onreadystatechange = function(){

    var DONE = 4;
    var OK = 200;

    if (ajaxData.readyState === DONE) {
        if (ajaxData.status === OK) {
            console.log(ajaxData.responseText);
        }else{
            console.log("ERROR : " + ajaxData.status);
        }
    }
};
ajaxData.send(inputUserName);
}
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    echo"TestInPHP";
?>
```

For now all I want to do is echo the username back to console, I'm sure the syntax is something simple, I just cant figure out what it is.

---

> Here is an edit for the working code thanks to SuperKevin in the
>   comments below.  This code will take the string in the username and
>   password fields in HTML by the JS, send it to PHP and then sent back
>   to the JS to output to the browser console window.

index.html

```
<input type="text" name="userID" id="userName" placeholder="UserID">
<input type="password" name="password" id = passW placeholder="Password">
<button type="button" id = "button" onclick="attemptLogin()">Click to Login</button>
```

script.js

```
function attemptLogin(){

var inputUserName = 
JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("userName").value);
// console.log(inputUserName);
var inputPassword = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("passW").value);

var cURL = 'ajax.php?fname='+inputUserName+'&pass='+inputPassword;


var ajaxData = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajaxData.open('GET', cURL, true);
ajaxData.onreadystatechange = function(){

    var DONE = 4;
    var OK = 200;

    if (ajaxData.readyState === DONE) {
        if (ajaxData.status === OK) {
            console.log(ajaxData.responseText);
        }else{
            console.log("ERROR : " + ajaxData.status);
        }
    }
};
ajaxData.send();
}
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['fname']; 
  echo $_GET['pass'];
?>
```

Comment: Search on how to pass query parameters or post parameters with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example of how you would make a vanilla call.

This is our main file, call it **index.php**.

```
<script>

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php", true);
    xhttp.send();

</script>
```

Here's our server script. **delete.php**

```
<?php

echo "HELLO THERE";
```

Now, if you wanted to pass data to your script you can do the following:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "delete.php?fname=Henry&lname=Ford", true);
xhttp.send();
```

To access this data you can use the global `$_GET` array in php. Which would look like this:

```
$fname = $_GET['fname']; 
$lname = $_GET['lname'];
```

Obviously, you have to sanitize the data, but that's the gist of it.

For a much more in depth tutorial visit [W3Schools Tutorial PHP - AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp).

Comment: Thank you! I was sending the data incorrectly with the send() function, turns out this is similar to CURL that I'm using on the php side where the data is sent via URL! I've updated my code above to show working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the data sent to your php with :

```
<?php
   print_r($_GET); //if it's send via the method GET
   print_r($_POST); //if it's send via the method POST
?>
```

So, in your case it will be something like :

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['username'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using `jQuery` then don't pay attention to my answer and stick to the pure `javascript` answers.

With jQuery you can do something like this:

**First Page:**

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'sportsComparison.php',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
         BaseballNumber = 42,
         SoccerNumber = 10
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

which will send the value `42` and `10` to `sportsComparison.php` with variable names `BaseballNumber` and `SoccerNumber`. On the `PHP` page they can then be retrieved using `POST` (or `GET` if that's how they were sent originally), some calculations performed, and then sent back.

**sportsComparison.php:**

```
<?php
$BaseballValue = $_POST["BaseballNumber"];
$SoccerValue =  $_POST["SoccerNumber"];

$TotalValue = $BaseballValue * $SoccerValue;

print "<span class='TotalValue'>".$TotalValue."</span>";

?>
```

This will return a `span` tag with the class of `TotalValue` and the value of `420` and print it in the console.

Just a simple way to do `ajax` using `jQuery`. Don't forget commas in the parameter list.